Setting password policies: password complexity. password aging, lockout settings and No of failed logins in ubuntu 22.04
How can I set password policies: password complexity. password aging, lockout settings and No of failed logins in Ubuntu 22.04? Specifically if I want password expiration in 60 days, not reuse the 6 last passwords and the password to contain at least 1 Lowercase, 1 Uppercase, 1 Number and 1 special character. Additionally how to set login failed attempts to 5 and Lockout user for 15 min? I'd like to specify that I don't want to apply these changes for root user
